# Refer to nested objects without full qualification

Tags: kotlin

I have code (all of which I control) that looks like the following:

```
class FirstVeryLongName {
  object ObjectA
  object ObjectB
  object ObjectC
}
class SecondVeryLongName {
  object ObjectB
  object ObjectD
}
```

The code I need to write is equivalent to

```
operation1(FirstVeryLongName.ObjectA, FirstVeryLongName.ObjectB)
operation2(SecondVeryLongName.ObjectB, SecondVeryLongName.ObjectD)
```

...except that the repeated uses of the very long names add a lot of clutter.

Here is something I hoped would work, but doesn't seem to:

```
FirstVeryLongName.run {
  operation1(ObjectA, ObjectB)
}
```

...which I wasn't able to make work, even if I tried moving `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` into the companion of `FirstVeryLongName` and writing

```
FirstVeryLongName.Companion.run { ... }
```

...which I had hoped would give unqualified access to the objects, as it would have for a `val` in the companion object.

One thing I specifically want to *avoid* is typealiases or importing them as aliased names.  I want it to be obvious *without* cross-references or manually looking at the imports where these are all coming from.

Is there some trick that would let me write this code and write  `FirstVeryLongName`, `ObjectA`, and `ObjectB` each exactly once?

Comment: can you share the signature of `operation1` and/or `operation2`? If the code is under your control, the easiest is probably to just adapt it... if you divide the code appropriately static imports should be appliable... but probably I don't see the whole picture yet...

Comment: Part of why static imports aren't appropriate is the name conflict between FirstVeryLongName.ObjectB and SecondVeryLongName.ObjectB.

Comment: I saw that, but I don't see your `operation*`-signature yet ;-)

Comment: Also: can you elaborate a bit, why you have chosen this structure?

Comment: @Roland the `VeryLongName`s are configurable types, and the objects inside them are configuration options (some of which are classes with their own configuration options).  So they're actually constructor arguments: `ConfigurableObject(Option1(setting = foo), Option3)`.  Most, but not all, configuration options are defined nested inside `ConfigurableObject`.  Some configuration options have the same names between different things being configured.

Comment: I don't know... does it really make sense to have an `object` as part of a configurable type? Do you have some code to share? maybe I see it better then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me that it isn't working the way you tried it.

The class name itself is no instance and `run` or `with` therefore doesn't apply. It's the same as just writing the package name and nothing else. This doesn't work either.

Regarding the `Companion`-approach, I assume you implemented the following:

```
class FirstVeryLongName {
  companion object {
    object ObjectA
    object ObjectB
    object ObjectC
  }
}
```

and a usage such as:

```
with(FirstVeryLongName.Companion) {
  operation1(ObjectA, ObjectB)
}
```

Actually this could work as long as you have such properties defined for the companion (this applies to functions as well). Actually that is also something you mentioned yourself. You may want to look at the generated byte code to see what an `object` actually corresponds to, if you didn't do it already. If you did, you can skip the rest of this paragraph ;-) Think of it as if it were just nested classes. In the example above we therefore have 3 nested classes inside the `Companion`-class, which is inside the `FirstVeryLongName`-class.

From Kotlin the access to the singleton `INSTANCE`-field is hidden from you. In the Kotlin code `FirstVeryLongName.Companion.ObjectA` can represent both, the type and the singleton instance reference. The context is relevant.

As you can't use class-names-only or part of an import-statement in `run`/`with`, you can't also simplify the access to the singleton instance in this way.

You can however do something as follows. Note: I clearly do not recommend this approach as is (I do not believe that you really need both: the `object` and the `val`). Maybe you can also use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions-and-declarations) there? There is most probably an easier way to structure your code, but without appropriate context I can only guess... I may be wrong):

```
class FirstVeryLongName {
  companion object {
    val ObjectA = FirstVeryLongName.ObjectA // can you use an object expression here?
    val ObjectB = FirstVeryLongName.ObjectA
    val ObjectC = FirstVeryLongName.ObjectA
  }
  object ObjectA
  object ObjectB
  object ObjectC
}
```

Now the `run`/`with` works as you desire, but now it actually accesses the `val`-reference which points to the `object`:

```
with(FirstVeryLongName.Companion) {
  operation1(ObjectA, ObjectB)
}
```

Just showing a simple example using an object expression. You may either want to have a common superclass, interface or, if you do not mind, you can even use `object : Any()` here:

```
class FirstVeryLongName {
  companion object {
    val ObjectA = object : interfaces.ObjectA  { /* ... */ }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Usage still looks the same. Now only the signature of `operation1` may differ.

Comment: I don't think you're quite right that `run` or `with` don't apply.  From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) on companion objects: "The name of a class used by itself (not as a qualifier to another name) acts as a reference to the companion object of the class (whether named or not)."

Comment: ok... you are right in the sense that I wasn't completely clear... what I meant: it depends on the context... if you write `FirstVeryLongName.ObjectA` this is just a qualified access to `ObjectA` (object) and under the hood the compiler transforms it to something like `ObjectA.INSTANCE`... something like `with(partOfQualifyingName) { ObjectA }` is not supported and I have my doubts whether it really would make sense to have something like that (how could you then easily differentiate between real objects and parts of qualified names? or whether you access a property of that singleton?).